# php is failing to call shell script (js -> php -> sh)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to execute a shell script from webpage. So I started with a simple arithmatic sum program. Webpage has two fields and a submit button. If user clicks submit button, javascipt validates and then calls php file through `ajax`. Php file extracts the arguments and call `sum.sh` with those arguments.
But i'm unable to do it. Here is my code.

**design3.html**:

```
 <body>
 <form action='' method='post'>
        <center>
           arg1: <input type='text' name='t1' id="arg1"/> <br><br>
           arg2: <input type='text' name='t2' id="arg2"/> <br><br>
           <input type='submit' name='use_button' value='Sum' onclick="addContent()"/>
        </center>
    </form>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    function addContent(){
        var a = document.getElementById('arg1').value;
        var b = document.getElementById('arg2').value;

        if(a == "" || b == "") {
            alert("Please fill all fields");
            return;
        }

        var request = $.ajax({
                   url: "add.php",
                   type: "POST",
                   dataType: "html",
                   data: {functionname: 'add', arguments:[a, b]}
         });

         request.done(function(msg) {
                   alert(msg);
          });

          request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                   alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
          });

    }

</script>
</body>
```

**add.php**:

```
<?php
if (is_ajax()) {
    if( isset($_POST['functionname']) ) {
        switch($_POST['functionname']) {
            case 'add':
                $var1 = $_POST['arguments'][0];
                $var2 = $_POST['arguments'][1];
                $cmd = 'sh ./sum.sh'.' '.$var1.' '.$var2;
                $output = shell_exec($cmd);
                echo $output;
                break;
         }
     }
}

function is_ajax() {
    return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}
?>
```

**sum.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=$1
var2=$2
echo `expr $var1 + $var2`
```

I'm new to this JS and PHP. But tried hard to do this. If I'm testing seperately it's working. When I write html and php in same file without JS then my script is working. If I'm not calling `sum.sh` script file in php, it is working. Coming to total integration it is failing. I'm getting this error from browser alert `Request failed: error`.

Comment: tried to disable the is_ajax function? maybe is that

Comment: Security Note: Escape your arguments before using them in your exec command! see [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) and [escapeshellcmd](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php). Otherwise user could execute arbitrary code on your shell.

Answer (score 2):

You POST to the server

```
functionname: 'add'
```

It does not match with your server-side test

```
switch($_POST['functionname']) {
    case 'connect':
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought the problem is in javascript or php. But the problem is in my html code. One of my friend solved this problem.
He told I took submit button. So he changed the type of button `submit` to `button`. Now it's working fine.

Change this code:

```
<input type='submit' name='use_button' value='Sum' onclick="addContent()"/>
```

to:

```
<input type='button' name='use_button' value='Sum' onclick="addContent()"/>
```